# Conversion to Dalvik format failed in my console

Tags: android, dalvik

I have one problem in my project Android. My project compile, but when I run the application, I've got this message "Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lbiz/source_code/base64Coder/Base64Coder;"

I've tryed to clean my project too, but nothing.

Can Anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normally caused because you have 2 identical libraries added to your project.

Remove one of them and the problem will be resolved.